# How can I make this button in a function open another View Controller with Swift?

Tags: swift, button, mapkit, android-mapview

When you search a location in my app, a pin with a title appears in that location. Next tot that title there's a button, where I am right now is that when you tap it it prints ("Disclosure Pressed!") in the func mapView. How can I code it so that instead of printing that it opens another View Controller with that location appearing again in a mini map this time?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

protocol HandleMapSearch {
func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil
var selectedPin:MKPlacemark? = nil


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestLocation()

    //
    let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
    resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
    //
    let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search for places"
    navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
    //
    resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    definesPresentationContext = true
    //
    locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView
    //
    locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self
    //
    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Action:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}

extension ViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("error:: \(error)")
}
}

extension ViewController: HandleMapSearch {
func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark){
    // cache the pin
    selectedPin = placemark
    // clear existing pins
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
    annotation.title = placemark.name
    if let city = placemark.locality,
        let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
        annotation.subtitle = "\(city) \(state)"
    }
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}
}
extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    pinView?.canShowCallout = true
    pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
    return pinView
}
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        print("Disclosure Pressed!")
    }
}



}
```

Comment: in Xcode indent your code to the right before copying it and just paste it will keep xcode formating

Comment: Sure, thanks. Do you know how to make the button open that other View Controller?

Answer (score 0):

To open New view controller you need to write this line in button click event:

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GoToViewController", sender:self)